# Inserting query results from MS SQL 2008 to MYSQL via VB2010

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Im a newbie in VB2010 & in MYSQL Database. 
I have 2 database one on MS SQL 2008 (BigData) and another on Mysql. I have written some code in VB2010 to fetch data from SQL2008 and insert into MySQL. My goal is to transfer all data from MS SQL to MySQL as quick as I can thats why I created a simple vb script that will act as middleware to transfer data from MS SQL to MySQL.

My Headache is, almost 1 hour to transfer the 28,000 records from MS SQL  to MySQL database. Is there any easiest way to transfer the data or I need to enhance my VBScript program. Please help to improve my VBScript below.

Thank you in advance.

Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Imports System.Data

Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1

```
Dim SQLConnectionSQL As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection
Dim connectionStringSQL As String = "Data Source=solomon;Initial Catalog=testapp;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=Passw0rd"


Dim connectionString As String = "Server=192.168.1.199; User Id=gil; Password=Passw0rd; Database=testapp"
Dim SQLConnection As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection
Dim oDt_sched As New DataTable()


Private Sub btnRetrieve_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnRetrieve.Click
    Dim con_Solomon As String
    Dim connection As SqlConnection
    Dim command As SqlCommand
    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim sql As String

    Dim str_carSql As String

    lblCounter.Text = 0

    con_Solomon = "Data Source=solomon;Initial Catalog=MARYLANDAPP;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=Passw0rd"

    sql = "SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(DocType)) as DocType, LTRIM(RTRIM(cust_classID)) as cust_classID, LTRIM(RTRIM(salesman)) as salesman, LTRIM(RTRIM(CustId)) as CustId, LTRIM(RTRIM(name)) as name, LTRIM(RTRIM(ClassID)) as ClassID, LTRIM(RTRIM(invoice_no)) AS refnbr, invoice_delv_date AS Delv_DocDate, Age, AR_Amount, LTRIM(RTRIM(STATUS)) as STATUS, LTRIM(RTRIM(AGE_GROUP)) as AGE_GROUP, LTRIM(RTRIM(company)) AS comp, '' AS Deposit_Date, Credit_Limit, LTRIM(RTRIM(Terms)) as Terms, LTRIM(RTRIM(customer_name)) AS ShipName, LTRIM(RTRIM(PO_Number)) as PO_Number, LTRIM(RTRIM(Kob)) as Kob, LTRIM(RTRIM(check_date)) as check_date FROM a_aging_ardoc_report"

    connection = New SqlConnection(con_Solomon)

    Try
        connection.Open()
        command = New SqlCommand(sql, connection)
        command.CommandTimeout = 420
        adapter.SelectCommand = command
        adapter.Fill(ds, "PO_Monitoring")
        adapter.Dispose()
        command.Dispose()
        connection.Close()


        ''****** MYSQL CONNECTION *****
        SQLConnection = New MySqlConnection()
        SQLConnection.ConnectionString = connectionString
        SQLConnection.Open()
        Dim sqlCommand As New MySqlCommand

        Dim delv_docdate, check_date

        For a = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1

            With ds.Tables(0).Rows(a)


                If Not IsDBNull(.Item(7)) Then
                    delv_docdate = .Item(7)
                Else
                    delv_docdate = ""
                End If


                If Not IsDBNull(.Item(19)) Then
                    check_date = .Item(19)
                Else
                    check_date = ""
                End If

                str_carSql = "insert into agingreportsummary(doctype,cust_classid,salesman,custId,name,classid,refnbr,delv_docdate,age,ar_amount,status,age_group,comp,credit_limit,terms,shipname,po_number,kob,check_date) " & _
                "VALUES('" & .Item(0) & "','" & .Item(1) & "','" & Replace(.Item(2), "'", "") & "','" & .Item(3) & "','" & Replace(.Item(4), "'", "") & "','" & Replace(.Item(5), "'", "") & "','" & .Item(6) & "','" & delv_docdate & "'," & Replace(.Item(8), ",", "") & "," & Replace(.Item(9), ",", "") & ",'" & Replace(.Item(10), "'", "") & "','" & .Item(11) & "','" & .Item(12) & "','" & .Item(14) & "','" & .Item(15) & "','" & Replace(.Item(16), "'", "") & "','" & Replace(.Item(17), "'", "") & "','" & .Item(18) & "','" & check_date & "');"


            End With


            sqlCommand.Connection = SQLConnection
            sqlCommand.CommandText = str_carSql
            sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next a

        SQLConnection.Close()

        MsgBox("Finish")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(str_carSql)
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a parameterised query instead of building a query for each row. That should improve things slightly since the statement wouldn't need to be prepared every time.

Add all the required parameters to the command.

Set the command text once, and change it to use parameters.

Inside the loop you would only set the parameter values and call the executenonquery method

This would have the added benefit of not being vulnerable to sql injection.

Hope that helps

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the prompt reply. Can you teach me how it works? Please... cause Im a newbie in VB2010. Thanks again.

Comment: That's not how this site works. Try it yourself and ask if you get stuck